# Which is the better, dropping and recreating FK constraints OR Disabling and enabling FK checks?

Tags: mysql, database, foreign-keys, flyway, disable

I have few columns in various tables of MYSQL database which were allocated more length than actually needed. So now I try to make them of proper length. They were VARCHAR(64) and I want to make them CHAR(36). Those columns are involved in Foreign Keys. These changes are going to be a new SQL file, which is run with Flyway Engine. Which of the two options is better?

1) drop the constraints and modify columns and recreate constraints.

2) execute `set foreign_key_checks=0`, alter columns and execute `set foreign_key_checks=1`.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are going to change the length its better to disable foreign_key_checks. Because it will affect only your current session (unless you mention global). so that it will not affect other session which depends on foreign key.